# Проблема в скорости записанного видео при помощи OPENCV

Tags: opencv

Сделал проект записи видео с экрана при помощи cvVideoWriter (opencv).Работает,качество картинки нормальное,но........скорость записанного видео значительно выше скорости видео на экране. Пробовал менять fps,пробовал менять параметр cvWaitKey - ничего не помогает.Может кто знает в чем проблема и как ее исправить ?

```css
#pragma endregion
 Graphics^ graph;
  Bitmap^ bitmap;
  CvVideoWriter *writer;
 
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

     
 const char *filename = "C:\\Users\\валера\\Pictures\\Video.avi";
 
 
   bitmap = gcnew Bitmap (Screen::PrimaryScreen->Bounds.Width,Screen::PrimaryScreen->Bounds.Height,Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb);  
   CvSize size = cvSize(Screen::PrimaryScreen->Bounds.Width, Screen::PrimaryScreen->Bounds.Height);
  
 writer = cvCreateVideoWriter(filename, CV_FOURCC('D','I','V','X'), 25, size, 1);
         assert(writer!=0); 
 
   backgroundWorker1->RunWorkerAsync();
  
  
   }
 private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    
     backgroundWorker1->CancelAsync();
     cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
 writer=nullptr;
    this->Close();
    }
private: System::Void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventArgs^  e) {
    BackgroundWorker worker;
    
    while(1){
   if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
                {
                    e->Cancel = true;
                    break;
                }
   else
   {
  
    graph = Graphics::FromImage(bitmap);  
   graph->CopyFromScreen(0,0,0,0,bitmap->Size); 
System::Drawing::Rectangle Rect(0,0,bitmap->Width,bitmap->Height);
   
 


     System::Drawing::Imaging::BitmapData^ bmData = bitmap->LockBits(
   System::Drawing::Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap->Width, bitmap->Height) ,
   System::Drawing::Imaging::ImageLockMode::ReadWrite,bitmap-> PixelFormat);
  
      frame = cvCreateImage(cvSize(bitmap->Width , bitmap->Height) , IPL_DEPTH_8U , 3);
  frame->imageData = (char*)bmData->Scan0.ToPointer();
  
  
  cvWriteFrame(writer, frame);
    
  
      cvWaitKey(1);
   bitmap->UnlockBits(bmData);
   frame=nullptr;
    }
    }
   }

};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю насчёт записи, но для вывода видео я регулировал его скорость так:

1. До цикла вывода видео объявляю `unsigned long ShowStartTime;`
2. В начале итерации цикла: `ShowStartTime = GetTickCount();`
3. В конце итерации цикла:

   do{   cvWaitKey(1);}
   while(ShowStartTime - GetTickCount() < 19);

где 19 - задержка перед следующей итерацией, с которой можно экспериментировать.

В отличие от обычной установки `cvWaitKey`, в данном случае учитывается время на обработку кадра.

Comment: Не понял этого   do{ cvWaitKey(1);}
while(ShowStartTime - GetTickCount() < 19);

Comment: Если этот цикл выполнять в конце итерации цикла получения кадра, то можно эффективно управлять задержкой перед получением следующего кадра с учётом времени, затраченного на обработку кадра. Таким образом можно получить ожидаемый и "ровный" FPS

Comment: Спасибо,теперь понял. Сейчас попробую

Comment: GetTickCount - -это из "Windows.h"  ?

Comment: winbase.h, который входит в Windows.h. Я подключаю просто Windows.h

Comment: Спасибо. Я просто вначале не понял ,почему цикл do-while , а не while. Сейчас сообразил

Comment: Это чтобы в любом случае подождать 1 мс, так как циклы со сложной обработкой лучше искусственно подтормаживать, иначе они могут сильно грузить проц. Я так обжёгся на while "без тормозов" - простой вывод в консоль грузил i5 на 30%. Загрузка упала в ноль после Sleep(1) в конце итерации ))

Comment: Что грузит процессор это я заметил. У меня на цикле на Ptntium 4   92%/. Сейчас освободился от дел и буду пробовать Ваш вариант

Comment: К большому сожалению метод не работает на записи - пробовал от <1 до <1000. Скорость не меняется и она выше скорости видео на экране

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59558/discussion-between-valeryv-and-iceman).

Comment: Решил проблему следующим образом ( я, конечно, понимаю,что мой способ напоминает ремонт ноутбука молотком и зубилом,но он работает. Понимаю.что не могу (или еще не умею) увеличить продолжительность каждого frame я просто решил увеличить количество одинаковых frame.Я повторяю строку cvWriteFrame(writer, frame) несколько раз подряд.Фактически это цикл while (N<m){N++;cvWriteFrame(writer, frame);}Меняя m меняю скорость

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему следующим образом ( я, конечно, понимаю,что мой способ напоминает ремонт ноутбука молотком и зубилом,но он работает. Понимаю.что не могу (или еще не умею) увеличить продолжительность каждого frame я просто решил увеличить количество одинаковых frame.Я повторяю строку cvWriteFrame(writer, frame) несколько раз подряд.Фактически это цикл while (N